# Show object values ten times in loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to loop the object output with event, but for some reason I am missing something. [codepen](https://codepen.io/swgj19/pen/KKWavzr)

```
let cereal = {
    healthy: 'wheaties',
    sugary: 'Trix',
    boring: 'Bran',
};

//console.log(cereal.healthy[]);

const cerealDisplay = document.getElementById('cereal');

const changeColor = (e) => {
    cerealDisplay.style.color = 'red';
    setTimeout(() => {
        cerealDisplay.style.color = 'blue';
    }, 2000);
};

for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    cerealDisplay.innerHTML =
        cereal.healthy + ', ' + cereal.sugary + ', ' + cereal.boring;

    cerealDisplay.classList.add('cereal');
    cerealDisplay.addEventListener('click', changeColor);
}
```

Comment: You're overwriting the innerHTML every time. You probably want to use `+=` instead, like `cerealDisplay.innerHTML +=`. Additionally, "not looping" is not a descriptive question, please review [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In the future you can also use `console.log()` to verify what code is being executed, which would have told you your loop is running, and helped you find the problem.

Comment: Your `cerealDisplay` has nothing to do with the cereal js object. also you commented console.log is incorrect and won't work if you try to run it, it should be either `cereal.healthy` or `cereal['healthy']`

Comment: I will do better at explaining it next time. I updated the title question. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop, I believe that you want to create a new child and add it to the display div.

When you click on one of the children, you need to access it via `event.target`.

```js
let cereal = {
  healthy: 'Wheaties',
  sugary: 'Trix',
  boring: 'Bran',
};

const cerealDisplay = document.getElementById('cereal');

const changeColor = ({ target: cerealChild }) => {
  cerealChild.style.color = 'red';
  setTimeout(() => {
    cerealChild.style.color = 'blue';
  }, 2000);
};

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  const cerealChild = document.createElement('div');
  cerealChild.textContent = Object.values(cereal).join(', ');
  cerealChild.classList.add('cereal');
  cerealChild.addEventListener('click', changeColor);
  cerealDisplay.append(cerealChild);
}
```

```css
#cereal {
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="cereal"></div>
```

Comment: right, but my goal was to show those three values 10x. I am just practicing learning Javascript.

Comment: @StephenW I looked at your external snippet and addressed this.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I was going for. I will do better at explaining it next time. I updated the title question.